# GVim: find out if guifont is available

Tags: vim, fonts

I'm sharing my vim settings across a number of different machines, which don't neccessarily have exactly the same configuration.

Now if my favourite font is only available on one system but not another, this leads to the problem that gvim uses a fallback which may not be the best choice.

So: Is there a way to do multiple tries of `set guifont=...` and somehow check whether it was successful? Or is there a way to provide a list of fonts to try?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can give Vim a list of fonts:

```
set guifont=Monaco:h24,Inconsolata-gz:10
```

Vim will try the first then the second…

`:h guifont` doesn't tell if there's a limit to the number of choices.

Comment: Funny how i'm using vim for years now, but it never occured to me to actually read the doc on that one.

Comment: Just a small tip for future generations. This is one of the cases in which you cannot add space after the comma. Otherwise you are going to get an error on the first font which isn't present on current system.

Answer (score 3):

Detection / fallbacks may work in this instance, but things get hairy when you also want different font sizes (due to different display resolutions), window sizes, local commands, etc.

A more extensible system than switching on `$HOSTNAME` or similar schemes is checking for a "local" `.[g]vimrc` and sourcing that in:

```
" Put this in ~/.gvimrc:
" Source system-specific .gvimrc first.
if filereadable(expand('~/local/.gvimrc'))
    source ~/local/.gvimrc
endif
```

This way, all special settings are localized and do not complicate your shared config.

Answer (score 1):

Following the accepted answer is likely the right method in most cases, but this is a work around. Platform specific to unix like gtk2 systems only. First, create a function checking for the font using a shell command:

```
function! Font_exists(font)
  exec system("fc-list -q '" . a:font ."'")
  return v:shell_error == 0
endfunction
```

Then use it with whatever logic is desired. E.g.:

```
if Font_exists('Iosevka Term')
  set guifont=Iosevka\ Term\ Light\ 9
elseif Font_exists('Inconsolata')
  set guifont=Inconsolata\ 9
elseif Font_exists('Terminus (TTF)')
  set guifont=Terminus\ (TTF)\ 9
endif
```